# create a table using file contents python

Tags: python

if the file for example contains:

- A: GHJIG
- B: AHYFASF
- C: IYDDFG

`f = open(example.txt)`

I want to store the file contents in a table and then the program should ask the user to enter a character and print the line without the alphabet.

- input: A
- output: GHJIG

how to do it?

Comment: Might use a dict to store the map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    content = file.readlines()

my_dict = {}

for line in content:
    split = line.split(':')
    my_dict[split[0]] = split[1]

input = raw_input("Choose a letter")

if input in my_dict:
    print my_dict[input]
```

It would be better to use a OrderedDict from collections, because default dictionary has a not a precise order.

Comment: Is it possible to not use a dictionary?

Comment: Of course. Here's the list way:

with open('test.txt','r') as file:
 content = file.readlines()
input = raw_input('Choose a letter: ')

for line in content:
 split = line.split(':')
 if input == split[0]:
  print split[1]

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution below, you can provide a useful message if the user enters any alphabet which is not present in your txt file.

```
with open('/home/pydev/Desktop/t1.txt', 'r') as file_obj:
    content = file_obj.readlines()

sample_dict = {}
for value in content:
    sample_dict[value.split(':')[0]] = value.split(':')[1]

input_key = raw_input("Please enter an alphabet: \n")
print sample_dict.get(input_key, "No value exists")
```